# Do I have to recompile my Gan every batch, to prevent the discriminator from learning?

Tags: keras, generative-adversarial-network

I have a Gan like so

```
generator = Model(g_in, g_out)
generator.compile(...)

discriminator = Model(d_in, d_out)
discriminator.trainable = True
discriminator.compile(..)

discriminator.trainable = False

gan = Model(inputs=.., outputs=..)
gan.compile(..)

#iterate over epochs and batches, without compiling
```

It learns and gives acceptable output. However I get the warning:

*"keras\engine\training.py:490: UserWarning: Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected trainable weights, did you set `model.trainable` without calling `model.compile` after ?
  'Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected trainable'"*

If I recompile the discriminator and gan every batch, the warning disappears, but one iteration takes much longer and training speed is slower.

```
for epoch:
  for batch:

    fakes=generator.predict_on_batch(batch)

    discriminator.trainable = True
    discriminator.compile(..)

    discriminator.train_on_batch(batch, ..)
    discriminator.train_on_batch(fakes, ..)

    discriminator.trainable = False
    discriminator.compile(..)
    gan.compile(..)

    gan.train_on_batch(batch,..)
```

Which one of them is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected and there's no need to recompile every batch. Keras has an open bug about this: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8585

The replies there have some examples of how to by pass the warning, I'm not going to repeat them here. There's also a reply which gives great advice on how to verify you're really training what you're supposed to be training if you feel unsure about the specifics of your model: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8585#issuecomment-385729276